# Error on install of dos2unix via homebrew

Tags: homebrew, dos2unix

Getting an error when I try to install dos2unix via homebrew.  brew doctor has no suggestions, and other install work like a charm.  No idea where to start tracing it.

```
$ brew install dos2unix
==> Downloading http://waterlan.home.xs4all.nl/dos2unix/dos2unix-6.0.3.tar.gz
Already downloaded: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/dos2unix-6.0.3.tar.gz
==> make prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/dos2unix/6.0.3 CC=cc CPP=cc CFLAGS= CFLAGS_OS=
cc   -DVER_REVISION=\"6.0.3\" -DVER_DATE=\"2013-01-25\" -DVER_AUTHOR=\"'Erwin Waterlander'\" -DDEBUG=0 -I/usr/local/Cellar/gettext/0.18.3.1/include -DD2U_UNICODE -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DENABLE_NLS -DLOCALEDIR=\"/usr/local/Cellar/dos2unix/6.0.3/share/locale\" -DPACKAGE=\"dos2unix\"  -c unix2dos.c -o unix2dos.o
pod2text man/man1/dos2unix.pod > man/man1/dos2unix.txt
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/pod2text: Permission denied
make: *** [man/man1/dos2unix.txt] Error 126
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On my system `/usr/bin/pod2text` had no execution rights. After changing that by executing the following command I had no problem installing `dos2unix`:

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/pod2text
```